# Looping through all Folders and Sub Folders to get the files of Box

Tags: c#, box-api, boxapiv2

I have setup a folder that is shared and can be accessed without being logged into Box. 
Is there a way to loop through the folders and sub folders to get the files from Box without having me to provide an api key or token? I am trying to do this in C# and the Box API.

To all that voted to close this question. Please clarify how the question is unclear.

Comment: why do you want to loop through all folders and sub folders? It seems like a really bad idea to loop through all folders/files. Maybe Box API can offer something to make it better/faster?

Comment: I want to allow the users to download the files from our intranet without using the box widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use an API key, but use the client-credentials grant.  That way you can download the files without providing a specific user, but the downloads will still be attributed to your application.

Comment: where can I find the documentation about this?